# Create Terrain Ruggedness Index (TRI) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, terrain

I just started to use raster files, and I want to create a Terrain Ruggedness Index (TRI), using QGIS. 
Which layers must I use? Do I need to create the "Input file (DEM raster)" (in: Raster>Analysis>DEM (Terrain Models), or is it OK to use only a raster layer with elevation for each pixel?

Comment: check this https://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/terrain%20analysis/

Comment: Thank you! The problem is, when I use the raster layer with elevation data  to create a TRI (using QGIS), I get a interval of 0-22.16, and since I know it goes up to >600m, I don't know how to interpret this result or what is it I am doing wrong..

Comment: According to the document I quote you must be in level terrain, check the document it states how to interpret the results

Comment: So the interval I get [0-22.16] is in meters, and I should fit this in the Roughness Index? And I just realized I get different results if I use TRI or Roughness (in DEM (Terrain models)>Mode); which one shoud I use for this index?

Comment: according to the document: "it shows the change in elevation categorised as shown in the ruggedness index table"

Comment: from http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html: This command outputs a single-band raster with values computed from the elevation. Roughness is the largest inter-cell difference of a central pixel and its surrounding cell, as defined in Wilson et al (2007, Marine Geodesy 30:3-35).

Comment: Now it is more clear! Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Do you know how to change the size of the surrounding cells? For example, how do I calculate the differences between the elevation of a central pixel and the elevation of the surrounding pixels (ex.: using a buffer of 500m)?

Comment: sorry, I went to the gdaldem help and nothing tells me how to accomplish what you want to do. May be if you post it as a new question someone could help

Comment: I found this http://gis4geomorphology.com/roughness-topographic-position/ and this http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/reference-docs/Terrain_Ruggedness_Index.pdf, although, no comment about the cell size, and it is designed for arcmap....

Comment: Yes, I have seen that link but it tells me nothing about QGIS. I asked a new question regarding this problem, now using GRASS, but I'll try to have access to a ArcGIS software to perform these analyses! Thank you very much for your help!